# Using NLog in UserControl

Tags: c#, .net, logging, user-controls, nlog

I'm  trying to use NLog for my WindowsFormsControlLibrary but it isn't work. Is there any way to provide logging in .exe application that uses my Control.dll?

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

  <!-- make sure to set 'Copy To Output Directory' option for this file -->
  <!-- go to http://nlog-project.org/wiki/Configuration_file for more information -->

  <targets>
    <target name="file" xsi:type="File" fileName="${basedir}/${shortdate}/file.txt"
     layout="${stacktrace} ${longdate} ${message}" />
  </targets>

  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="file" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

Comment: "Doesn't work" isn't an error description. What is your problem? Furthermore, please show your logging code

Comment: I find decision in followng: Create instance of NLog in your application (instead in .dll) and simple using it in your dll. Dont't create instace of nlog in your controls!

Answer (score 0):

i also got this problem in this morning. Maybe, my solution is too late, but i will post here in case someone need. The reason why nlog cannot write file is because of missing Nlog.config, it's sound not reasonable ah ? But that's it , you must copy the Nlog.config to the **application** folder not your DLL folder , in your case it's the folder contain the application used your UserControl dll :)! 
Contact me if you cannot solve the problem with my solution : tanh1989@gmail.com